# Ошибка в Andoid Studio при запуске

Tags: android-studio

При запуске проекта выскакивает ошибка при построении `Content is not allowed in prolog.`. Очистка кэша не помогает. Лог:

> [Fatal Error] aapt2-3.3.0-5013011.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in
>   prolog.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
>
>   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.3.0-5013011.   Required by:
>   >       project :app
>   >     Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.3.0-5013011.
>   >     Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.0-5013011/aapt2-3.3.0-5013011.pom
>   >     Content is not allowed in prolog.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 4s 11 actionable tasks: 9 executed, 2 up-to-date

Comment: Полный лог ошибки покажите.

Comment: Ещё gradle скрипт хорошо бы приложить)

Comment: @Suvitruf он созданный при создании проекта

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте закрыть Студию и кеш почистить:

```
C:\Users\имя_пользователя\.gradle\caches
C:\Users\имя_пользователя\.android\build-cache
C:\Users\имя_пользователя\.android\cache
```

Comment: Данный способ не помог

Answer (score 1):

Решил данную проблему: удалите из командную опцию "--offline" (у меня было по умолчанию).
Также проверьте, чтобы не была установлена опция в Gradle "Offline work".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]